# pass reference to class inherited from abstract base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class

I want to pass a pointer to a class inherited from an abstract base class, but get an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error (when calling the function f()) in the following (much simplified) code

```
class A {
    double *pointer;
public:
    A(double *p)
    {
        pointer = p;
    };
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

class B :public A{
    double *pointer;
public:
    B(double *p_) : A(p_){};
    void f(){std::cout << pointer[0] << std::endl;};
};
```

if I call it e.g. like this

```
 double p[2] = {1.,2.};
 B b(p);
 b.f();
```

The problem doesn't seem to be there if the base class is not abstract, but I can't figure out what's wrong with the above code. Any help in solving this, and maybe suggesting a different way of achieving this kind of structure is greatly appreciated!

Comment: In class `B`, you declare a *new* data member named `pointer`. Therefore, objects of type `B` have *two* data members called `pointer`: One from class `A` and one from class `B`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that "pointer[0]" in f() ends up accessing the `pointer` member of the `B` class, not the `pointer` member of the `A` superclass.

And since it's not initialized, in your example, it's undefined behavior.

Just remove the declaration of `pointer` in `B`.

Comment: thanks, it works, I just have to make the declaration of pointer in A protected.